# How to query duplicate entries while getting non duplicate entries?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this..:

[image: Table]

I am trying to figure out how to query only one of the duplicate entries while still getting the non-duplicate entries?

```
$query = "SELECT id, size, color FROM `".$item."` WHERE size in (SELECT size FROM `".$item."`
                GROUP BY size HAVING COUNT(*)>1)";
$resul = $conn->query ($query);
if($resul->num_rows > 0){
    while($r = $resul->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $r["size"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: which row you want from the duplicated? The lowest / higher id? The most quantity?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do when using the [low-level SQL server driver](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using. **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Yes, I still have to switch everything over to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/DOGUNS29451)

This select the row with biggest id for each size:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.size, t1.color 
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
  ON t1.id < t2.id
 and t1.size = t2.size
WHERE t2.id IS NULL   // if no one is bigger than you, you are the biggest.
```

Now you filter the one with more then one row

```
 AND t1.size ( SELECT size
               FROM yourTable
               GROUP BY size
               HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: When I run this, I get nothing returned.

Comment: the first part ? or the whole query?

Comment: check again. the filter is size not id

Answer (score 0):

You can query like this:

```
SELECT size, color, quantity FROM `yourtable` group by size
```

But, it will show you the first row related to *Small*, like this:

[image: query result]